# Normalize pandas dataframe with all columns together

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to normalize a pandas dataframe with all columns together

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   x  y
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
```

I do

```
df_nor = (df-df.min())/(df.max()-df.min())
```

OUT:

```
In [10]: df_nor
Out[10]:
     x    y
0  0.0  0.0
1  0.5  0.5
2  1.0  1.0
```

How can I get column x and y be normalized together like

```
In [10]: df_nor
Out[10]:
     x    y
0  0.000  0.333
1  0.333  0.666
2  0.666  1.000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's NumPy tagged, here's one using the underlying array data -

```
In [54]: a = df.values # get underlying array

In [55]: pd.DataFrame((a-a.min())/(a.max()-a.min()), columns=df.columns)
Out[55]: 
          x         y
0  0.000000  0.333333
1  0.333333  0.666667
2  0.666667  1.000000
```

Alternatively staying closer to `pandas`, we could do -

```
In [79]: (df-df.values.min())/(df.values.max()-df.values.min())
Out[79]: 
          x         y
0  0.000000  0.333333
1  0.333333  0.666667
2  0.666667  1.000000
```